# 'AFFINE' is not defined PIL python

Tags: python, transform, python-imaging-library

I am using the transform method of the Image class.

```
import Image
im = Image.open('Image.jpg')
im1 = im.transform((1000,1000),AFFINE, (1,0,0,1,10,10))
```

The above code produces an error: NameError: name 'AFFINE' is not defined. 
If I use "from Image import *" it works:

```
from Image import *
im = open('Image.jpg')
im1 = im.transform((1000,1000),AFFINE, (1,0,0,1,10,10))
```

However, I don't want to override my previously defined methods and therefore I want to use "import Image". How can I make my first example work without having to use "from Image import *"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `im1 = im.transform((1000,1000),Image.AFFINE, (1,0,0,1,10,10))` prefix the variable with the module name.